# Finding closure of a space of sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

First we define the sets we have in mind:

- Let $l^p$ be the set of all sequences of real numbers for which $\sum |x_n|^p < \infty$
- $l^{\infty}$ the set of all bounded sequences of real numbers ( with norm $\lVert x_n \rVert_{\infty} = \sup_n |x_n|  $ )
- $A := \{ x \in l^{\infty} : x_n \to 0 \}  $
- $B := \{ x \in l^{\infty} : \exists N : x_n = 0 \forall n \ge N \}$

We want to show that $A$ is the closure of $B$ when the norm is $\lVert x_n \rVert_{\infty} = \sup_n |x_n|  $

and show that $l^p$ is the closure of $B$ when the norm is $\lVert x \rVert_p =   
 ( \sum |x_n|^p )^{\frac{1}{p}}$

The second task seems somewhat more tractable to me, since, informally, for any sequence $g$ in $l^p$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, we can always find another sequence $b \in B$ so that $b$ has all the same entries as $g$ until some point, and then all later entries of $b$ are zero. Then $g - b$ has $N$ many zero entries at its start, followed by a tail that (when $b$ is picked correctly) has an $l^p$ norm less than $\epsilon$. Written formally, this would give us that $d(b,g) < \epsilon$ and so $l^p$ would be the closure of $B$. Does this sound like a possible direction to go in?

The first, task is the one that is giving me trouble because I'm having trouble figuring out how to make things work with the $\sup$ norm. Since this norm only cares about the biggest entry in the sequence, I'm having a hard time picturing how the closure would work.

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=(x_{1},x_{2},...)\in A$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $N$ such that $|x_{n}|<\epsilon/2$ for all $n\geq N$, set $y=(x_{1},...,x_{N-1},0,0,...)$, then $y\in B_{\epsilon}(x)$ because $x-y=(0,...,0,x_{N},x_{N+1},...)$ so $\|x-y\|_{\infty}=\sup_{k\geq N}|x_{k}|<\epsilon$. So every ball centre at $x$ has some element of $B$, this shows that the closure of $B$ is in $A$. Of course, one should actually note that $B\subseteq A$.

Your way to tackle the second question sounds okay.